# Find by pk with in condition

Tags: php, yii

How can i `findbypk` with in condition

my query is

```
  $model = User::model->findBypk($id);
```

now i want to apply In condition that `UserRole` should be in `(1,2)`

Comment: What lib do you use ? Wich dev/stack context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a criteria

```
criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('id', array(1,2));
$resultModels = User::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

The $resultModels return a collection of  models that contain the required rows

Or if you want  single model  you can use find

```
criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('id', array(1,2));
$model = User::model()->find($criteria);
```

Comment: Thanks but id is unique i want to use in condition in userRole and findbypk instead of finall()

Comment: but if you use a in clause the resulting roes can be more that one  .. in your sample is you have (1,2) you could obtain  two rows..

Comment: You can use find .. instead of findByPk .. i have update the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
$Criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->compare('id',$id);
$criteria->addInCondition('userRole', array (1,2));
$models = User::model()->findAll($Criteria);
```